# Set a variable based on the #of a url -- window.location.hash

Tags: jquery

so lets say i have a url www.hello.com#one

i know i can grab the has value

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
alert (hash);
```

but rather then write (i know the below is not propper code):

if var hash = one then set var hashValue to 1

else

if var hash = two then set var hashValue to 2

else etc etc

is there a better way to write this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var map = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2
};

var hashValue = map[hash.substring(1)];
```

This will set hashValue to `undefined` if hash doesn't exist in the map.

Comment: Note that `location.hash` will contain the `#` as well.

Comment: sorry not entirly sure what you mean i tired: var hash = window.location.hash;
var map = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2
};
var hashValue = map[hash];
alert (hashValue);

Comment: is there a reason locally it works if i press refresh but not if i just hit return in the browser window

Comment: @sluap Pressing return on a page with a hash doesn't reload it, just changes the hash, and fires some hash change event.

Comment: thank you ill look into a way of sorting that one. again thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `switch` block to do this.

```
switch(location.hash.replace('#', '')){
    case "one": newhash = 1;
    break;
    case "two": newhash = 2;
    break;    
};
alert (newhash);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the hash returns the hash value including the # sign

So hash='#one' not 'one'. Apart from that you could use a switch case
    switch(hash)
    {
    case '#one':
    hashVar=1;
    case '#two':
    hashVar=2;
    }

if you are willing to change the hash style to say #tab1 #item1 or simply #1 instead of #one or something, u cud get the number pretty easily

```
var hash = window.location.hash;//hash=#tab1 say
var number=hash.replace('#tab',"");
alert(number);
```

That's it. this way, the number can be as large as you want. In the first case you'd have to manually assign the variable for each number

So if there were 100 items you'd have a pretty long list

Comment: thank you i know i will only have about 4 but ill keep this one too